# how to convert list of strings into list of dictionaries values

Tags: python

I have a list as below:

```
list=["a","b","c"]
```

I want to convert into below format:

```
data=[{"key": "a"},{"key": "b"},{"key": "c"}]
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: Be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
list_of_dicts = [{"key": value} for value in my_list]

#output
[{'key': 'a'}, {'key': 'b'}, {'key': 'c'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not appropriate to name your variable `list` because it's a python built-in function. If you look at my answer you will realize that I have used the `built-in` list function. You can also  choose to avoid iteration like `for-loop` if you wish to, by using `map` and `lambda`:

```py
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

data = list(map(lambda x: {"key": x}, my_list))
print(data)
```

---

```
[{'key': 'a'}, {'key': 'b'}, {'key': 'c'}]
```

Comment: A simple list comprehension as proposed by @Meny is less complicated and much faster

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list to create a new list of dictionaries, each with a key of "key" and a value from the original list, here is an example

```
givenList = ["a", "b", "c"]
resultList = []
for item in givenList:
    resultList.append({"key": item})
```